# Error: A value of type 'Post' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter

I am currently experimenting with API. I created a model class to handle the data.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Post {
  final int id;

  Post({
    @required this.id,
  });

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      id: json['graphql']['shortcode_media']['id'] as int,
    );
  }
}
```

after that, I created a HttpServiceclass to call an API

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:insta/model/abstractmedia.dart';

class HttpService {
  final String postsURL = "https://www.instagram.com/p/B-mvkeIlQcP/?__a=1";

  Future<List<Post>> getPosts() async {
    Response res = await get(postsURL);

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {

      Map<String, dynamic> body = jsonDecode(res.body);

      List<Post> posts = body.map(
            (dynamic item) => Post.fromJson(item),).toList();
      return posts;

    } else {
      throw "Can't get posts.";
    }
  }
}
```

but I am getting error in httpService class on line 17

```
Error: A value of type 'Post' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>'.
```

how to fix this error i am new in flutter

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your code

```
List<Post> posts = body.map((dynamic item) => Post.fromJson(item),).toList();
```

the var `item` is the key of your map `body`. One way to solve it is to change `Post.fromJson(item))` to `Post.fromJson(body[item]))` or use `body.forEach`

Comment: I already tried `Post.fromJson(body[item]))` but still, getting the same error.. any idea?

Comment: I also have this error on the same line `The return type 'Post' isn't a 'MapEntry', as defined by anonymous closure.`